# Angularjs - How to call an array inside JSON data to html

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have a little problem.. I've got this JSON data:

```
[
{
    "students": {
        "student_id": "2",
        "student_school": "1",
        "student_name": "Charles"            
    },
    "parents": [
        {
            "parent_id": "2",
            "parent_school": "1",
            "parent_name": "Tim"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "students": {
        "student_id": "3",
        "student_school": "1",
        "student_name": "Johnny"
    },
    "parents": [
        {
            "parent_id": "3",
            "parent_school": "1",
            "parent_name": "Kate"
        }
    ]
}
]
```

The problem is that I try to call to my html page by angular:

```
{{student.student.student_name}}
```

Yeah it works but when I want to call the parents data it doesn´t...

```
{{student.parents.parent_name}}
```

Comment: add the code that doesn't work, your attempt to call the parents

Comment: How could that code possibly work for that Json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
<div ng-repeat="student in data">
    {{student.students.student_name}}
    {{student.parents[0].parent_name}}
</div>
```

Or define function in scope called for example `getParentDescription` and than

```
<div ng-repeat="student in data">
    {{student.students.student_name}}
    {{getParentDescription(student)}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because parents is an array. You must specify the index (0 in your case). See the response here : [How to get value from a nested JSON array in AngularJS template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590184/how-to-get-value-from-a-nested-json-array-in-angularjs-template)

Answer (score 0):

You can't access child scopes directly from parents. See the [comment by Vittorio](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/LDNz_TQQiNE/ygYrSvdI0A0J) suggesting`<ng-repeat="child in parent.children"/>` also [Binding to Primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714884/difficulty-with-ng-model-ng-repeat-and-inputs)

Comment: Why do you think he has multiple scopes? But yeah, we can only guess without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing student is from an ng-repeat where you go through each object in the array.

Take a closer look at your JSON. While "students": {} points to an object, "parents": [] points to an array. Fix your JSON and it'll be fine